# Can I get an RSS feed of changes to a Google Doc?

Tags: google-drive, rss, google-forms

If I would like to track edits to a Google Doc or inputs to a Google Form by receiving an RSS feed thereof, how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw this answer on a [blog](http://www.labnol.org/forums/topic/create-rss-feed-from-a-google-doc):

```
First the document in question must be publicly accessible. Private documents 
cannot have an RSS feed. 

Click the SHARE button in the top right and share it with others as 
"Collaborators" and not just "Viewers". Next, click the link on the same page,
toward the right that says "View RSS".
```

Comment: This functionality has been REMOVED by google. Yay for downgrades and ignoring user requests! There are *many* help requests for this feature in Google Docs help..

Answer (score 3):

In, for example, a Google Spreadsheet, you can use the File/Publish command. It lets you create a RSS feed for the spreadsheet.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: @pwned is this still possible?... i have tried and failed to create a feed url for the doc link!!!!

Comment: seems like it is removed