# Can I have an RSS for Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, rss

Is there a way to get an RSS feed for all documents created in Google Docs which are visible to me?

EDIT: I found [someone here](http://www.feedreader.com/node/2407) suggesting that a URL like `http://docs.google.com/feeds/EMAIL@ADDRESS.HERE/private/full?alt=rss&v=3` could work, and the Google Docs icon appears in my reader, but I can't come up with an email/username/password that work.

EDIT2: The [Docs docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25467&printable=1) say the "Docs list settings" "Editing" tab has an "RSS Feeds" option, but mine doesn't have that. Is it a feature of their paid edition?

Comment: Neither works for me either: I get a 'Resource unavailable.' message in the first case, and don't have any 'rss feeds' options.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11797/can-i-get-an-rss-feed-of-changes-to-a-google-doc - you may need your doc to be public to allow something like this.

Answer (score 2):

The link you have posted is expired so I would imagine that is either not possible or never existed.

Either way from the information presented with the Google Docs features it is not currently possible.